# Why does mod_rewrite sometimes appear to do an external redirect when the trailing slash is missing?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI} -f [or]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI}index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) static/$1
```

All of them successfully serve files inside the `static` directory without needing to have the `static/` in the url. The only difference is that when I don't have a trailing slash, the `static` directory is added to the URL like an external redirect.

Thus,

http://example.com/products/index.html --> http://example.com/products/index.html

and

http://example.com/products/ --> http://example.com/products/

but,

http://example.com/products --> http://example.com/static/products/

Is there a way to make it so that the index file is served from the `/static/products` directory without showing the `static` directory in the url like the other two scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that there's a simpler way to go about this, but I finally came up with a combination that works:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI}index.html !-f  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f  
RewriteRule ^(.+) static/$1/

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI}index.html -f [or] 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI} -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+) static/$1
```